# ArrayDeque, работает не так как ожидаю

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции

Проблемы с пониманием работы `ArrayDeque`, а именно с заданием размерности.

```
Deque<String> data = new ArrayDeque<>(5);
```

После в цикле из консоли добавляем туда строки,

```
if (!data.offer(command)) {
    System.out.println("Полна коробочка(");
}
```

Ожидаю после добавления 5 элементов получить `false`. Хотя в документации сказано:

> Resizable-array implementation of the [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) interface. Array
>   deques have no capacity restrictions;

1. Как добиться желаемого поведения без горотьбы чего-то на подобии этого:

   ```
   if (airport.size() < 5) {
       airport.offer(command);
   } else {
       System.out.println("Полна коробочка(");
   }
   ```
2. При каких условиях добавление элемента вернёт `false` или исключение?

Comment: Вы просто таким образом задаете начальный размер, который может увеличиваться по мере использования очереди. Никаких ограничений это не накладывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать [BlockingDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html) вместо `ArrayDeque`.

Comment: То что надо! `BlockingDeque<String> deque = new LinkedBlockingDeque<String>();`